# <activity> vs. <activity/>. What is the difference?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, tags, compatibility

When looking at most sites (including SO), most of them use:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

insted of

```
 <activity android:name=".Complaints"> </activity>
```

- What are the main differences between the two, if any?
- Are there valid reasons to use one instead of the other?
- Are there valid reasons to use combine them?
  Does using  come with compatibility issues, seeing it is not very widely used?

Comment: Its XML tags.. you can close either way

Comment: Also _When looking at most sites (including SO),_ are you looking at android apps or website?

Comment: If <activity> supports nested inner tags and you would need them, you would choose option 2. But in general both variants do the same.

Answer (score 0):

First type is short way, else no difference at all but you can this as of if you have additional tags inside activity you will be using second type as you mentioned else it's up to you in which you feel comfortable go for that

Answer (score 0):

- What are the main differences between the two, if any?

  > No there is no difference between both of them both are valid

> **1.** The XML Schema of the `AndroidManifest` file allows empty-elements. An element with no content is said to be empty. The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag

**`<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />`**

> **2.** when you need to supports nested inner tags in your **`<activity>`** tag than you should use  for example

```
<activity android:name=".Complaints"> 
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>
   </activity>`
```